# mocking hasMany relation in laravel 5.1 unit test

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit

For a unit test in laravel 5.1 I am trying to test a cascading delete function of the Client model, which, with the recursive flag set, should also delete all users associated with the client. 
I want to use a mock user adn test only wether the delete function on the user is called, so I wont have to use the database, and to apply the same principle to other tests in the future.

at the moment the test fails because I cannot find a way to make the client model retreive the associated user without firing a query.
I think I need to mock the hasMany relation defining function of the client, but i have not found a way.

the client model:

```
class Client extends Model
{



    protected $table = 'clients';

    protected $fillable = [];



    public function casDelete($recursive = false){
        if($recursive) {
            $users = $this->users()->get();
            foreach($users as $user) {
                $user->casDelete($recursive);
            }
        }
        $this->delete();
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

the user model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'client_id'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function casDelete($recursive = false){
        $this->delete();
    }

    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }

}
```

the test:

```
class ClientModelTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    function testCasDelete(){
    $client = factory(Client::class)->create();
    $user = factory(User::class)->make(['client_id' => $client->id]);

    $observer = $this->getMock('user');
    $observer->expects($this->once())->method('casDelete');

    $client->casDelete(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use the factory to make the User, you need to associate a mock user to the `$client`.

Comment: @apokryfos Ok, and how would one do that? I tried something like `\Mockery::mock('Client')->shouldReceive('users')->andReturns($mockedUser)`, but that wouldnt be returned to the actual tested client

Comment: `$users = $this->users()->get();` will run a database query regardless. You will need to mock the client as well specifically the `users()` method should return another mock whose `get()` method returns the mocked user.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using DatabaseTransactions, this mean you want to persist the data in the database. And when you are using create() from the factory still you are using the database, so either you should not use the database at all or if you want you to use the database then you can simply solve the problem. but what I can suggest is this solution, which I'm not using the database init.

```
    $user = \Mockery::mock();
    $user->shouldReceive('casDelete')->andReturnNull();

    $queryMock = \Mockery::mock();
    $queryMock->shouldReceive('get')->andReturn([$user]);

    $clientMock = \Mockery::mock(Client::class)->makePartial();
    $clientMock->shouldReceive('users')->andreturn($queryMock);
    $clientMock->casDelete(true);
```

This way you can be sure that you have called casDelete on each user model.
this is a very simple test case, you can extend it in the way you like base on what you want to achieve.